# How can i return radiobutton selected value within extended idenity model within

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, radiobuttonfor

I am new to ASP.net MVC. I am stucked right now. i extended the identity model to include bio data like firstName, LastName, Gender etc.

I want to have the Gender rendered as radio button, I am able to run app without any error, but it will not submit the registration. This issue started after i change the gender from textbox to radio button. here is my code.

Part of my model:

```
    [Display(Name = "Middle Name")]
    [MaxLength(25)]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [MaxLength(25)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Gender")]
    public string Gender { get; set; }
```

My controller:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {


            var member = new MemberInformation
            {
                Id =
                    Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + DateTime.Now.Year +             DateTime.Now.Month + DateTime.Now.Day +
                    DateTime.Now.Hour,
                FirstName = model.FirstName,
                LastName = model.LastName,
                MiddleName = model.MiddleName,
                Gender = model.Gender,
                ContactAddress = model.ContactAddress,
                MarialStatus = model.MarialStatus,
                Occupation = model.Occupation,
                MobilePhone = model.MobilePhone,
                RegistrationDate = DateTime.Now,
         }
```

my view:

```
    <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Gender, new {@class = "col-md-2 control-label",})
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Gender, "Male")
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(Model => Model.Gender,  "Male") 
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Gender, "Female")
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Gender,  "Female")
      </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: The code you have shown will work fine and bind correctly (although the labels wont act as labels and you have invalid html because of duplicate `id` attributes). If its not binding, then its due to other code you have not shown us

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your `Model => Model.Gender` expression is causing some confusion because Model already means something in that scope.

LabelFor is also odd when used that way, use an html label to simplify things

```
    <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Gender, "Male")Male</label>
    <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Gender, "Female")Female</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Html.RadioButtonFor` the same model property twice it creates two controls with the same ID. As the postback only cares about names, not IDs, you need to override the IDs, as below:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Gender, "Male", new {id = "GenderMale"})
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Gender, "Female", new { id = "GenderFemale" })
```

This creates radiobuttons that map to Gender, but with different IDs.

Note - you should include the `new { id = "Whatever" }` bit, otherwise it'll duplicate IDs again.

Comment: It makes no difference whether you use `RadioButton()` or `RadioButtonFor() (and the strongly typed `RadioButtonFor()` is always preferred)

Comment: You edit is fine and adding the `id` is good practice, but this does not address OP's issue as to why its not binding :)

Comment: This is the error i am seeing when i run the application debugging mode.                                                                                                       "The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe. "